# What is the equivalent of SelectedValuePath and SelectedValue in Winforms ComboBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Does someone know what is the equivalent of `SelectedValuePath` and `selectedValue` from WPF comboboxes to WinForms? I tried with `ValueMember` and `Value` but that doesn't work...

Comment: Of what type of control are you trying to get these properties for? Textbox, button, listView, etc.?

Comment: I am trying to get this properties for ComboBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WPF, [`SelectedValuePath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selectedvaluepath(v=vs.110).aspx) gets or sets the path that is used to get the `SelectedValue` from the `SelectedItem`. It's exactly what [`ValueMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember(v=vs.110).aspx) serves in Windows Forms, it gets or sets the path of the property to use as the actual value for the items of `ComboBox`.

In windows forms when you want to use data-binding with a `ComboBox`, you should use this properties:

- [`DataSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8160f6f(v=vs.110).aspx)
  An object that implements the `IList` interface or an `Array`.
- [`DisplayMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember(v=vs.110).aspx)
  The name of an object property that is contained in the collection specified by the `DataSource` property. If the specified property does not exist on the object or the value of `DisplayMember` is an empty string (""), the results of the object's `ToString` method are displayed instead.
- [`ValueMember`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember(v=vs.110).aspx)
  epresenting a single property name of the DataSource property value, or a hierarchy of period-delimited property names that resolves to a property name of the final data-bound object.
- [`SelectedValue`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)
  An object containing the value of the member of the data source specified by the `ValueMember` property.

**Example**

Put a `ComboBox` and a `Button` on your form and handle `Load` event of `Form` and `Click` event of `Button` like below below. By click on `Button` you will see the selected item of `ComboBox` will be changed to *Two*. Don't forget to register event handlers for events.

```
public class Category
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var categories = new List<Category>()
    {
        new Category(){Id=1, Name= "One"},
        new Category(){Id=2, Name= "Two"},
        new Category(){Id=3, Name= "Three"},
    };

    this.comboBox1.DataSource = categories;
    this.comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
    this.comboBox1.ValueMember = "Id";
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.comboBox1.SelectedValue = 2;
}
```

Comment: And When I set Path with ValueMember  for example `ValueMember="ProductId"` hot to get SelectedValue I tried with Value but nothing ?

Comment: You should set `DataSource`, `DIsplayMember` and `ValueMember`, then `SelectedValue` contains the selected value. Which is value of the `ValueMember` property of the `SelectedItem` of `DataSource`.

Comment: When I want to change informations and I put `comboBox.SelectedValue=product.ProductId"` which I set as ValueMemebr=`ProductId` doesn't work

Comment: The answer contains all you need.  I don't know what settings you are using.

Comment: I believe the post completely answers your current question *What is the equivalent of SelectedValuePath and SelectedValue in Winforms?*. If you have any other question, for example about the settings that you performed in data-binding and it doesn't work, it's better to ask a new question.

Comment: Surely it will work in windows forms too. It has been working for years and will work for future :). You just need to learn more about windows forms data-bindings :)

Comment: No It doesn't work I set everything as you said DataSource, DisplayMemeber, ValueMember to productId and When I want to set SelectedValue it doesn't set my combo on that productId value

Comment: If you were me, could you add more help without any extra information? :)

Comment: Yes I voted last one helped but I will not vote if doesn't help me which is true

Comment: I have no rating now I got my fist up vote I voted but it doesn't show me anything before @Reza Aghaei

Comment: Check the example I posted for you and let me know the result.

Comment: I want to select row from datagridView and populate controls with that info everything works but combo doesn't

Comment: Ask a specific question about what you said in your last comment. The current post completely answers your question. I also added an example for you to learn more :)

Comment: you was right man on same form it works but I want to set it combo from another form Sorry man I was wrong I tried your answer I will ask new again in WPF works and I rarely do WinForms

Comment: You're welcome :) - Have you ever noticed to the check mark near the answer? It's for accepting the post. Click on it and read more about it [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/308647) :)

Comment: Now it is the problem to set comboBox.SelectedValue from another form :) I must ask

Comment: Suppose someone with the same question come to this page. He is looking for *What is the equivalent of SelectedValuePath and SelectedValue in Winforms ComboBox?* He doesn't know what is in your mind. Usually they look for accepted answer. Also take a look at most voted answers. So accepting an answer helps both future readers to find the solution more simple. Also it helps to the community to have more focus on un-answered questions.

Comment: I'm , just trying to help you to use the site better :)

Comment: you were right man apology your answer was correct on this quest I didn't specify correctly my quest

Comment: Now I will ask again be there :)

Answer (score 2):

Here are the conversions:

```
 WPF                       : WinForms

 .SelectedIndex            | .SelectedIndex
 .SelectedItem             | .SelectedItem
 .SelectedValue            | .SelectedValue
 .SelectedValue.ToString() | .SelectedText
 .SelectedValuePath        | .ValueMember
```

Comment: `SelectedValuePath` is equivalent to `ValueMember`.

Comment: SelectedValue doesn't set the value which you specified with ValueMember I set comboBox.DataSource, DisplayMemebr, ValueMemebr and when I want to set comboBox.SelectedValue It doesn't work

Comment: @jhony3 I found that `SelectedValue` only worked if I assigned the collection of items to `cbox.DataSource`, rather than adding them to `cbox.Items` (`cbox.DataSource` is how it's done in Reza Aghaei's answer). How are you putting the items in your ComboBox? `DisplayMember` worked either way by the way.

Comment: I did't like that i put the list of items in cBox.DataSource I set DisplayMemebr and ValueMember but it doesn't work when I set cBox.SelectedValue=2 my combo is still on initial values

Comment: @jhony3 It works for me. I'd have to see your code to guess what you did differently.

Comment: @RezaAghaei @EdPlunket So the `.SelectedValuePath` is equal to the `.ValueMember` if the `.DataSource` is set?

Comment: Yes, it works like `SelectedValuePath`.  Take a look at [documentations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.valuemember(v=vs.110).aspx). Read the first line, also *Property Value* and *Remarks* part.

Comment: @RezaAghaei help with my new question