# How to set SelectedItem in WinForms ComboBox depending on a condition

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a WinForms application with ComboBox in it. I want to programatically select an item depending on its value.

I tried using `IndexOf` but it requires the whole object, I want to do it only by value. `Items` are `ObjectCollection` and I can't use `Linq` on it (or don't know how).

In one place I'm setting its source like that:

```
private void SetItems()
{
    var items = new List<ComboItem>(3);
    //Add items to the list
    combo.BeginUpdate();
    combo.DataSource = items;
    combo.ValueMember = "Value";
    combo.DisplayMember = "Name";
    combo.EndUpdate();
}
```

```
private class ComboItem
{
    public int Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then (in other place) I want to set selected item depending on the value. E. g. if I had the combo values:

```
"Option1": 2,
"Option2": 5,
"Option3": 10
```

I would like to do something like:

```
combo.Items.SelectedValue = 5
```

And have in combo selected `Option2`. Is it even possible?

Comment: Take a look at duplicate post to see usage of `SelectedValye`. Also if you are interested to use `Linq`, you can do it this way: `comboBox1.SelectedItem = comboBox1.Items.Cast<ComboItem>().Where(x => x.Value == 5).FirstOrDefault();`. Remember to add `using System.Linq;`.

Comment: @RezaAgaei It appears that in the meantime some values from my combobox dissapeared and `SelectedValue` eventually worked. However I wanted also to find something like your solution with `Cast<>`. So if you would post your comment as an answer I would accept it.

Comment: `SelectedValue` example: [What is the equivalent of SelectedValuePath and SelectedValue in Winforms ComboBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38765322/3110834).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** When setting up `DataSource` and `ValueMember` for a `ComboBox`, to select specific value, use `SelectedValue` property.

*Example - Assign SelectedValue*

```
comboBox1.SelectedValue = 5;
```

**2)** When all the item of `ComboBox` are of type of `T`, you can searching between items using `ComboBox.Items.Cast<T>()` assign it to `SelectedItem`.

*Example - Search using ComboBox.Items*

Since all items of your `ComboBox` are of type of `T`, you can use linq `Cast<T>` to cast `ObjectCollection` to `IEnumerable<T>`. For example:

```
comboBox1.SelectedItem = comboBox1.Items.Cast<ComboItem>()
    .Where(x => x.Value == 5).FirstOrDefault();
```

Remember to add `using System.Linq;`.

Comment: Just keep in mind, since your `DataSource` is a `List<T>` you can use this as well: `comboBox1.SelectedItem = ((List<ComboItem>)comboBox1.DataSource).Where(x => x.Value == 5).FirstOrDefault();`